# How to use a returned boolean value from a method?

Tags: java, methods, boolean, joptionpane

Not sure if I am wording this correctly however I'm trying to get an input from a user which then checks if the answer is 'yes', and if it is I want it to return 'true', then use this in my main method.

```
[Main Method]
String inputFromUser = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Yes/No?");

checkBoolean(inputFromUser);

if(inputFromUser = true) {
System.out.println("Yes, true!"); }

else if(inputFromUser = false) {
System.out.println("No, false!"); }

public static boolean checkBoolean(String inputFromUser) {

boolean returnValue;

if(inputFromUser.equals("yes")) {
returnValue = true; }

else {
returnValue = false; }
}
return returnValue;
}
```

With this code I get incompatible types in my main method where I am doing inputFromUser = true. Required string but receives boolean.

`error: incompatible types. if(inputFromUser = true) {
required: String
found: boolean`

How can I make this work exactly? There's probably an answer on this site already but I do not know how to word the question exactly.

Comment: **inputFromUser** is of `String` type and **true** is `boolean`, `if(inputFromUser = true)`, are you trying to assign `true` value to `String`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
checkBoolean(inputFromUser);

if(inputFromUser = true) {
System.out.println("Yes, true!"); }

else if(inputFromUser = false) {
System.out.println("No, false!"); }
```

to

```
if(checkBoolean(inputFromUser))  //This is same as if(checkBoolean(inputFromUser)==true)
System.out.println("Yes, true!"); 
else
System.out.println("No, false!");
```

In your current code,you try to assign a `String` to a `boolean` which makes no sense. I think you meant `==` there as you want to compare them.But even if you change that,it is wrong as you compare a `String` with a `boolean` value. Another way would be t store the return value of the method in a `boolean` variable and use it in the `if`.The below code does that:

```
boolean check = checkBoolean(inputFromUser);

if(check)  //This is same as if(check==true)
System.out.println("Yes, true!"); 
else
System.out.println("No, false!");
```

Also,your `checkBoolean` method can be shortened into a single line using

```
return inputFromUser.equals("yes");
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because `inputFromUser` variable is of type String and you are comparing it with boolean.

You can do the following:

```
boolean doContinue = checkBoolean(inputFromUser);
if (doContinue) {//intead of if(inputFromUser = true) {
     System.out.println("Yes, true!");
}
```

And similarly you could change your other conditions. Remember even if your `inputFromUser` were meant to be a boolean you need to compare it with "==" with true instead of "="

Answer (score 1):

First, `inputFromUser = true` is an assignment statement that assigns the value `true` to the variable `inputFromUser`. The check should use `==` instead, i.e. assuming `inputFromUser` had been of type boolean, it should be `inputFromUser == true` (knowing that you can simply go with `if(inputFromUser)` in that case).

However, in your case `inputFromUser` is of type `String` and this is cause of the compilation error. You should assign the return value of `checkBoolean` to a variable and use that instead of `inputFromUser`:

```
boolean answer = checkBoolean(inputFromUser);
if(answer) {
   System.out.println("Yes, true!");
} else {
   System.out.println("No, false!");
}
```

Or you can skip using `checkBoolean` and go with:

```
if(inputFromUser.equals("yes")) {
   System.out.println("Yes, true!");
} else {
   System.out.println("No, false!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Boolean is a different data type to a string. Its not simply a string that contains 'True' or 'False'. Instead of assigning a boolean string to the returnValue variable, just return true or false and remove the return statement from the end. This way you'll only be dealing with boolean values and not strings

Answer (score 0):

Look at the first line of your code.

The datatype you used is String but you are requesting for a Boolean datatype from the user.

Go ahead and change String to Boolean and recompile your program